# Protractor paste list of numbers into text field

Tags: protractor

I am currently trying to use protractor to upload multiple numbers eg, 23245, 23343, 34324 into a text field these numbers can be copied out of a excel spread sheet id column and pasted into the text field on the application. The application will then add the ids onto a table. Each id will have a new row. Does anyone know if this can be done. Currently I am only sending one number into the text field. But the text field can also receive multiple numbers...

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand the question, could you provide more context? What are multicity numbers?

If I were to send multiple numbers to a text field, I would probably:

```
<element>.sendKeys("1 \n 2 \n 3 \n 4 \n");
```

Or something similar. Please provide more information about the question so I/we can help better.

N

NOTE: I ORIGINALLY HAD THE SLASHES THE WRONG WAY, IVE EDITED THE ABOVE SNIPPET TO NOW BE CORRECT, MY BAD!

Comment: I updated the sescription thanks.. No i tried that it didnt work it just went in as 1 /n 2 /n 3 /n 4 /n and added a new row to the table with a id of "1 /n 2 /n 3 /n 4 /n"

Comment: Sorry, I got the slashes facing the wrong way, it should be \n. that should definitely work!

Comment: No still adds them on the same line. I tryed manualy copying the numbers myself and then run protractor using this <element>.sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord(protractor.Key.CONTROL, "v"));. That worked put i dont realy want to do a copy each time before i run the test. M

Comment: How bizarre, can you post some snippets of your code? In my code this is what I'm doing: <element>.sendKeys(text + "\n");

Comment: Its the same as yours insertIds.sendKeys("\n 1 \n 2 \n"); i also tried insertIds.sendKeys(1 + "\n"); and insertIds.sendKeys("1" + "\n");. No good either